# Linux: Measuring network consumption per remote host

Tags: linux, network-monitoring

Is there a way to measure the network consumption to a specific IP port.
I am running 2-3 process with multiple threads which connect to a remote server and I need to know the exact used network bandwidth from my server to the remote server.
My server runs under Linux - unfortunately I have no access to the involved network components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far, as I know, you can measure bandwidth out of the box only on specific interface.

To measure traffic by ports or IP's you have to use accounting software. For example [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure whether you need to know active flow or cumulative usage.  For the latter and other more involved data gathering, the aforementioned ntop is an excellent choice.

If you just need something quick and dirty to see the active connection flows on a NIC, you can try the [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) command.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that ntop doesn't scale well (this was a couple of years ago).  I am now using a combination of fprobe and nfsen to do bandwith usage monitoring.  See my notes [here](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Installing+nfsen).

Comment: You are generating netflow, it's not needed. And one more, wire-speed packet capturing: http://www.ntop.org/PF_RING.html

Comment: My problem wasn't so much that ntop wouldn't capture, it was that after a while it started generating links to itself that wouldn't work.  Also my setup above lets me have the listener (fprobe) be on a different computer than the usage calculator (nfsen) as well as do other analysis to the traffic activity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using pktstat as ntop looked good, but was a hazzle to install. it gives exactly the required breakdown.